# Finding ANSI escapes in raw terminal output not making sense

Tags: linux, unix

Can someone clear up what these escape codes mean, and provide a reference? I can't see a reference for them. I am using xterm, ubuntu 10.

Reference: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

From that reference, the closing square bracket "]" does not seem to be an escape. So can't map the escapes below: "[?1034h", and "]0;" - anyone know what these are and where I can get references for them?

```
\x1b[?1034h \x1b]0;me@myos:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the the [Xterm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) reference that code sets the the 8-bit input mode.

```
P s = 1 0 3 4 → Interpret "meta" key, sets eighth bit. (enables the eightBitInput resource).
```

Comment: That last one looks like `Change Icon Name and Window Title to P t .`, assuming the `:` is actually a BEL character. It is preceded by the OSC sequence.